# Is -r mandatory for grep?

Tags: grep

In a directory I have a file that contains the word `string`.
When I do: `grep "string" .` no results are returned.
But when I do `grep -r "string" .` the file is returned.
Why is `-r` option needed? It does not look inside internal subdirectories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not mandatory. `grep "string" .` means look for `string` in a file called `.`. If you want to run `grep` on all files in the current directory, use `grep string *` and if you want to look in all files in all subdirectories recursively, do `grep -r string`.

Comment: But in the version `grep -r "string" .` the `.` is interpreted as start from `.` directory?

Comment: You usually want to use `grep "string" filename` You're giving it '.' which is a directory (the current directory). If you want grep to search in a file, give it a filename, not a directory.

Comment: @Jim I never said anything about `grep -r "string" .`, I said `grep -r string` with no `.` but it doesn't matter, the two are equivalent. Yes, with `-r` the `.` (which is implied if absent) is interpreted s start from `.`. Why is that strange? `-r` means search through all files in this directory and its children, so it will find the file. With no `r`, grep will search through the _files_ you give it, if you just give it `.` it will treat it as a file and attempt to search through it, ignoring any other files you have not mentioned in the command line.

Comment: @valbaca:Ok but my question is if the third argument is interpreted as a filename or directory depending on the usage of `-r` or not

Comment: @Jim yes. Unless you run `grep -r` grep will treat its arguments as files. If you give it a glob (eg *txt) that will be expanded by the shell before `grep` sees it so again, `grep` will see a list of files. If run `grep -r`, it will treat the third argument as a path and search all files in that path.

Comment: . is ALWAYS the current directory. The `-r` flag tells grep to search recursively, which when given the current directory, means it's searching everything under the current directory, including the files immediately within the current directory.